# Linear independence of $y_1(t)=t^2$ and $y=t \vert t \vert .$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Just like the title says, I need to show that $y_1(t)=t^2$ and $y_2(t)=t \vert t \vert$ are linearly independent on the interval $-1 \leq t \leq 1.$

What I have done so far is to split the interval into two sub-intervals, one that is $-1 \leq t \leq 0$ and the other one that is $0 \leq t \leq 1,$ then I calculated the Wronskian for the functions in both intervals, that is 
\begin{equation}
W[y_1,y_2](t) = 
\begin{vmatrix}
t^2 & 2t \\ t^2 & 2t
\end{vmatrix}
= 0
\end{equation}
for the sub-interval $0 \leq t \leq 1,$ and I get a similar result for the other sub-interval, which prove that both are linearly dependent, and that's not the answer I'm looking for. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If such functions were linearly dependent their ratio would be constant, but their ratio equals $1$ on $(0,1)$ and $-1$ on $(-1,0)$.

Additionally, $y_2'(t)$ is not $2t$, it is $2|t|$.

Comment: Yes, that true about the derivative, but I specified that the wronskian is calculated on the positive side of the interval, so I'm assuming $y = t \vert t \vert$ is positive.

Comment: @lorenzattractor: in such a case the question is trivial, since $x|x|$ and $x^2$ are precisely the same function on $(0,1)$, and opposite functions on $(-1,0)$. So they are linearly dependent over these sub-intervals, but they clearly are independent over $(-1,1)$.

Comment: ok, I see what you mean, so my mistake was to split the interval into two sub-intervals, thanks. What I don't understand quite well is the result from their ratio, could you elaborate on that a little bit more?

Comment: @lorenzattractor: assuming linear dependence on $(-1,1)$ we have $\alpha y_1(t)+\beta y_2(t)=0$, hence $$\frac{y_1(t)}{y_2(t)}=-\frac{\beta}{\alpha}$$ for any $t\in(-1,1)$.

Comment: But the interval in the question is a closed interval, does this still hold?

Comment: @lorenzattractor: of course, but if they are linearly independent over $(-1,1)$ they are for sure linearly independent over a larger interval.

Answer (score 1):

Supppose $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
ay_1+by_2=0
$$
Then, for all $-1\leq t\leq 1$, you get
$$
at^2+bt|t| = 0
$$
Now if $t=-1$ and $t=+1$, you get two equations. Can you solve them for $a$ and $b$?